# Group where no appointment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, logic

The code below shows number of appointment each hour and 'No appointment' if no appointment is available.

I want to group consecutive 'No appointment' slot according to time

for e.g., The output of the current code is -

`10:00 AM to 11:00 AM -> No Appointment
11:00 AM to 12:00 PM -> No Appointment
12:00 PM to 01:00 PM -> No Appointment`

I want the output to be

`10:00 AM to 01:00 PM -> No Appointment`

The code is give below:-

```
<% @time_group = ['6:00:00','7:00:00','8:00:00','9:00:00','10:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','14:00:00','15:00:00','16:00:00','17:00:00','18:00:00','19:00:00','20:00:00','21:00:00','22:00:00','23:00:00'] %>

#Loop through each hour in @time_group
<% @time_group.each_with_index do |t,index| %>
  <% t1 = Time.parse(t) %>
  <% t2 = Time.parse(t) + 3600 %>
  <% @booked = Appointment.where(start_time: t1..t2 %>

  #Show time interval e.g 1:00 PM to 2:00 PM
  <%= Time.parse(t).strftime('%I:%M %p') %> to <%= (Time.parse(t) + 3600).strftime('%I:%M %p') %>

   #if appointment is available show appointment else show no appointment
  <% if @booked.size > 0 %>

    <% @booked.each do |app| %>
      <%= app.start_time.strftime('%I:%M') %>  
    <% end %>

  <% else %>  

    No Appointment

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, one might prepare the array:

```
@time_group = ['6:00:00','7:00:00', ...]
@stacked = @time_group.each_with_object([]) do |start, memo|
  range = Time.parse(start)..Time.parse(start)+3600
  booked = Appointment.where(start_time: range)
  if memo.empty? || !booked.empty? || !memo.last.last.empty?
    memo << [range, booked] # no sequenced empty slots
  else
    memo << [memo.pop.begin..range.end, booked] # merge ranges
  end
end.to_h # { ranges => booked }
```

And now—let’s output them:

```
<% @stacked.each do |range, booked| %>
  .....
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<% @time_group = ['6:00:00','7:00:00','8:00:00','9:00:00','10:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','14:00:00','15:00:00','16:00:00','17:00:00','18:00:00','19:00:00','20:00:00','21:00:00','22:00:00','23:00:00'] %>

#Loop through each hour in @time_group
<% @time_group.each_with_index do |t,index| %>
  <% t1 = Time.parse(t) %>
  <% t2 = Time.parse(t) + 3600 %>
  <% @booked = Appointment.where(start_time: t1..t2) %>


  #It will holds the No Appointment Timings into it
  no_appointment_array = []

  #if appointment is available show appointment else show no appointment
  <% if @booked.size > 0 %>

    #Calling the Function
    display_no_appointment(no_appointment_array) if not no_appointment_array.empty?


    #Show time interval e.g 1:00 PM to 2:00 PM
    <%= Time.parse(t).strftime('%I:%M %p') %> to <%= (Time.parse(t) + 3600).strftime('%I:%M %p') %>

    <% @booked.each do |app| %>
      <%= app.start_time.strftime('%I:%M') %>  
    <% end %>

  <% else %>  

   no_appointment_array << [Time.parse(t).strftime('%I:%M %p'), (Time.parse(t) + 3600).strftime('%I:%M %p')]

  <% end %>
<% end %>


def display_no_appointment(no_appointment_array)
  puts "#{no_appointment_array.first[0]} to #{no_appointment_array.last[1]} -> No Appointment"

  #It Clears all Previous No Appointment
  no_appointment_array.clear

end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to use if '@booked.present?' instead of 'if @booked.size > 0'

Have you tried something like this?
I have not test this code, it is almost an idea to a possible solution.
Hope that it could be helpful for you.

```
<% no_appointment_starts_at = nil %>
<% no_appointment_ends_at = nil %>

<% @time_group.each_with_index do |t,index| %>
    <% t1 = Time.parse(t) %>
    <% t2 = Time.parse(t) + 3600 %>
    <% @booked = Appointment.where(start_time: t1..t2 %>

    #Show time interval e.g 1:00 PM to 2:00 PM


    #if appointment is available show appointment else show no appointment
    <% if @booked.present? %>

    <% @booked.each do |app| %>
        <% unless no_appointment_ends_at.blank? %>
            <%= Time.parse(no_appointment_starts_at).strftime('%I:%M %p') %> to <%= (Time.parse(no_appointment_ends_at) + 3600).strftime('%I:%M %p') %>
            <% no_appointment_ends_at = nil%>
        <% end %>
        <%= Time.parse(t).strftime('%I:%M %p') %> to <%= (Time.parse(t) + 3600).strftime('%I:%M %p') %>
      <%#= app.start_time.strftime('%I:%M') %>
        <% no_appointment_starts_at = t2 %>  
    <% end %>

    <% else %>  
      <% last_appointment_ends_at = t2  %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```